# Sets whose decimal expansions form a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, integers

Write $\bar n$ for the decimal expansion of $n$ (with no leading `0`). For a set $S$ of natural numbers, let its **set of expansions** (in base 10) be $\bar S = \{\bar n \mid n \in S\}$. Is there a nice characterization of the sets $S$ such that **$\bar S$ is a regular language**?

Obviously adding or removing a finite number of values doesn't affect the regularity of $\bar S$, so what matters is only the “asymptotic” behavior of $S$, i.e. what it looks like above a certain threshold.

For [numbers written in unary](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-the-possible-sets-of-word-lengths-in-a-regular-language), there's a simple characterization: the corresponding set of representations is regular iff the set is ultimately periodic (i.e. it's of the form $\{a n + b \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, b \in F\}$ for some finite set $F$ and some constant $a$). An ultimately periodic set's set of expansions is a regular language: [it's a finite union of images of affine functions, which are regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/640/language-of-the-values-of-an-affine-function). There are other sets whose set of expansions is regular, such as $\{10^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. On the other hand, [the set of squares](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84050/is-square-numbers-written-in-binary-a-regular-language) doesn't have a regular set of expansions.

In general, how can $S$ look like when $\bar S$ is regular? Is there a simple arithmetic characterization of sets whose sets of expansions is regular?

Comment: Might still be the same answer (iff $S$ is ultimately periodic)?  Looks closely related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_sequence, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_arithmetic, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic#Presburger-definable_integer_relation, but I haven't dug through that and work out what it implies for your question.

Comment: @D.W. You can recognize powers of 10 (but not, say, powers of 2) in base 10 with a finite automaton.

Comment: Oh, right.  Good point.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: On second thoughts there doesn't seem to be a nice characterizations. What's nice about the numbers that contain a 3 when written out in decimal?